# How can I disable the git fileserver update schedule

Tags: salt-stack

I've set up a hook on my gitlab server to call `salt-run fileserver.update` from a `post-update` hook.

How can I disable the schedule that does a update every 60 to reduce the load on my gitlab server?

Answer (score 3):

The 60 seconds interval in which the Git filesystem is updated is defined by the `loop_interval` setting, which you can set in your master configuration file:

```
# The loop_interval option controls the seconds for the master's maintenance
# process check cycle. This process updates file server backends, cleans the
# job cache and executes the scheduler.
#loop_interval: 60
```

However, this interval controls not only the GitFS update schedule, but also a number of other maintenance tasks, so you should not increase this interval by too much.

From a quick [reading of the source code](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/22c6895d637239b43e7c6be8fbadf723c116e5de/salt/master.py#L246) (I'm not a core Salt developer though, so I might be mistaken), the GitFS update is hard-coded to run on the same schedule as these other maintenance tasks. There does not appear to be a way to disable or change the interval of only the GitFS update schedule.